# How to define a struct in a struct and reuse the same name twice?

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors, doxygen, naming

I have a simple **C** code example using a `struct` in a `struct`.

- I need for documentation (*doxygen*) a *named* struct, in my example `HermannS`.
- In *doxygen* I can refer to `age` with `\ref ottoS::HermannS::age`.
- In *doxygen* I can **not** use `\ref ottoS.name.age` etc
- For logic the name `HermannS` have to be the same.

Problem: But now the code create an *redefinition-error*

```
struct ottoS {
  struct HermannS {
    int age;
  } name;
};

struct otherS {
  struct HermannS {
    int size;
  } name;
};

int main ()
{
  return 0;
}
```

I get the following error-message:

```
main.c:16:10: error: redefinition of ‘struct HermannS’
   struct HermannS {
          ^~~~~~~~
main.c:10:10: note: originally defined here
   struct HermannS {
          ^~~~~~~~
```

Question: how to define a `struct` in a `struct` and reuse the name `HermannS` ?

better Question: is there a **gcc** extension (prefix) to hide this error?
→ but this would be a very **high** price to pay for a simple *doxygen* documentation issue.

Comment: *For logic the name HermannS have to be the same* - For what logic? There is no (valid) code in C I can imagine that needs the name tag of internal structure for any reason (except, perhaps, some preprocessor magic)

Comment: As I mentioned , it is *doxygen* which require the **named** struct to refer to the variable **age** with `\ref ottoS::HermannS::age`

Comment: @AndreasOtto Documentation should match code, not the other way around. There is no possible code where what you have would be valid.

Comment: @AndreasOtto: C cannot support what you're trying to do  in doxygen - you'll have to re-think your documentation approach.

Comment: @ThomasJager In fact documentation-driven programming is not a bad approach. It is just in this case the documentation seem to be over-specified and cannot be implemented.

Comment: @AndreasOtto, we do not dispute that you you want tagged structure types, and that this serves a purpose.  But you have not made clear why you insist that the inner structures need to have the *same* tag.  You say "for logic", but like Eugene, I see no likely reason for a requirement to have the same tag for two incompatible structure types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `struct` declaration does not create a new namespace in C the way it does in C++, so you can't create type names that are "local" to a `struct` type.  The tag name `HermannS` can only be used for one `struct` type definition.

C has four name spaces:

- all labels (disambiguated by `:` or `goto`);
- all tag names (disambiguated by `struct`, `union`, or `enum`)
- member names (disambiguated by `.` or `->`)
- all other names (typedef names, enumeration constants, variable names, function names, etc.)

Unfortunately, what you're trying to do won't work in C - you'll have to use a different tag name for each inner struct definition.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, as the compiler is telling you, and you really do not need to either. If you're not using that structure anywhere else, just don't name it:

```c
struct ottoS {
  struct {
    int age;
  } name;
};

struct otherS {
  struct {
    int size;
  } name;
};
```

The only other (obvious) solution is to name the two inner structs differently.

If your logic/code/documentation is based on the fact that you need those two *different* structures to have the same name, then I would advise revisiting the logic, because it looks flawed.

> is there a gcc extension (prefix) to hide this error?

No there is not. This is not a simple error, it's invalid C code: you are effectively defining two different types under the same name. The compiler will not be able to compile your code unless you avoid this.

Comment: for `doxygen` I need the name of the inner `struct` → that was the point.

Comment: @AndreasOtto well, you cannot have it. Either don't use a name or use *two different names*.

Answer (score 1):

C standard say in section 6.7.2.1 para 8

> The presence of a struct-declaration-list in a
> struct-or-union-specifier declares a new type, within a translation
> unit.

So *all* structs within the same translation unit share the same namespace.
`HermannS` is redefined thus code is ill-formed.

Some workaround would be adding a prefix with the parent structure name:

```
struct ottoS {
  struct ottoS_HermannS {
    int age;
  } name;
};

struct otherS {
  struct otherS_HermannS {
    int size;
  } name;
};
```

Latest C standards allow the implementation to accept characters from the extended set like `$`. It will help avoid collisions with more conventional names. It works with **gcc**. However, the code will no longer be portable.

```
struct ottoS {
  struct ottoS$HermannS {
    int age;
  } name;
};

struct otherS {
  struct otherS$HermannS {
    int size;
  } name;
};
```

It mimics `::` operator form C++ a bit. You could use some other unicode character and use it to postprocess your Doxygen documentation with sed-like tool. I mean replacing magic character with `::`.

Comment: Using `$` etc. has always been implementation-defined

Comment: @M.M, thanks for pointing that. The author of the question is using GCC, where `$` can be used.

Answer (score 1):

As the program is ill-formed it will not compile. However if `struct HermannS` is never used except the declaration then you could use the following trick.

If `HermannS` is removed then `ottoS.name` and `otherS.name` would become *anonymous structs* and the code would compile. All anonymous structs are independent types. Just pass `-DHermannS=` to the GCC's command.

```
gcc prog.c -DHermannS=
```

It will add a macro `HermannS` that expands to an empty token.

Do **not** pass this option to doxygen to let it generate a proper documentation.